# Prevent scrollbar to move on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, scroll, scrollbar

I would like to show the scroll bar, but prevent the user to move it.

I've managed to do this in all major browsers`(Opera, Safari, Chrome, Firefox)`but I couldn't manage to do it on Internet Explorer.`(8, 9, 10 and 11)`

To do it, I'm the `scrollTop`function combined with the `scroll` event like so:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function (e) {
    $('html, body').scrollTop(0);
});
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cus1tjL3/1/)

On IE the scroll bar goes down and then it goes up with some delay causing the site to flicker as it is scrolling for a while until it reaches the top again.

Any idea about how to deal with this?

Comment: How about you just remove the scrollbars to start?

Comment: I tested the demo with IE11, and the same it's do the same what you mentioned. Frustrating. MS guys are always do strange things :)

Comment: What are you intending to do with the variable `currentScroll`?

Comment: @epascarello I said "I would like to show the scroll bar". And I have my reasons for it.

Comment: @urbz it doesn't mind. You can remove it. I forgot to do it.

Comment: @Alvaro - I see. Btw, have you considered hiding regular `overflow` and implementing your own with css (& maybe jQuery)? Could be a possibility to overcome the IE issue.

Comment: Problem is the scroll event is not a 1 to 1, that is why a lot of scroll interactions are jerky. There should be plenty of questions on the subject. Normally this type of thing is solved with timeouts.

Comment: @epascarello I couldn't find anyone.

Comment: @alvaro problem is that event is generated when scroll is already done. And all browsers do the same - if you try to scroll mousewheel quickly in chrome, you will see the same effect

Comment: @Gromo, I can disable mouswheel with jQuery. That's not a problem. The problem is on the scrolling bar dragging.

Comment: @Alvaro I've just explained the reason of problem. Making hacks for IE is impossible task in some cases. Depending on things you need, you can select different ways. For example, use `position:fixed` to prevent scrolling when scrollbar dragged in IE for main content and set wrapper's height = main content's height (to show scrollbar) after page loaded. Or use `overflow:hidden` and write your own custom scrollbar that cannot be dragged.

Comment: @Gromo yep, I was just wondering if there's any way to do it. I might have to do some dirty tricks...